# How to change the style of a vector layer on a button click

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, wfs, style

Is there a way to change the style (e.g. color) of a vector layer on button click?

I have defined a vector layer like this:

```
   new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
            style: myStyle,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
            })
        });
```

Now I want when I press a button (which runs a function) to change the style with a new style which I define as:

```
   var newStyle = {
    fill: true,
    fillColor: "#ff0000"
};
```

Is something like this possible? I think I can not do this using redraw() or refresh() right?

One solution would be what I read [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227276/openlayers-vector-style-change-issue) (destroy the whole vector layer and build it again with the new style). But this doesn't seem very efficient either or?

**EDITED**

I tried this but doesn't seem to work. Instead I get all feature black:

```
   // ADD STYLING - DIFFERENT COLORS
                var styleContext = {
                    getColor: function (feature) {
                        var objectKeys = Object.keys(gidsAll); // use objectkeys to loop over all the object properties //use it to get the length
                        for (var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++){
                            if (Math.round(feature.attributes.__gid) === parseInt(gidsAll[objectKeys[i]], 10)) {
                                return "green";
                            }
                        }
                            return "red"; //no images on this line
                    }
                };

                // define Style
                var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
                    fillColor: "${getColor}",
                    fillOpacity:"1",
                    strokeColor: "${getColor}",
                    strokeOpacity: "1",
                    strokeWidth: 8,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    pointRadius: 8

                }, {
                    context: styleContext
                });

                // Define style when selecting the feature
                var selectStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
                    'pointRadius': 8,
                    strokeColor: "cyan",
                });

                // Define the stylemap (loaded in each feature)
                var featurestyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    'default': defaultStyle,
                    'select': selectStyle
                }); 


                wfs_layer_network.style = featurestyleMap;
                //then redraw the layer
                wfs_layer_network.redraw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do it by using redraw(), all you need to do is change the style of the layer first, then call the redraw function.

```
//reset the style of the layer to the style you defined
layer.style = newStyle;
//then redraw the layer
layer.redraw();
```

I created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wtwdnpma/) on JSFiddle that does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please help me once again. I have tested ur coded and modified in order to get a specific color depending on some values. But it doesn't work. The feature color doesnt change. Perhaps u can have a look in my edited question?